# How to add 5x5 table of rectangle shape

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I just joined and started learning JavaFX and am having trouble on how to add 5x5 table of rectangle shape with colors on it. Here is my progress:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();

    colors.add("ff0000");//red
    colors.add("#008000");//green
    colors.add("#0000ff");//blue
    colors.add("#ffff00");//yellow




    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.web(colors.get(rand.nextInt(4))));
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        grid.add(rect, row, col);
        if (row < 4) {
            row++;
        } 
        if (col < 4) {
            col++;
        }
    }

    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 500, 500);
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

I want it to look like this:

[image: Wanted Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++)
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.web(colors.get(rand.nextInt(4))));
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);    
        grid.add(rect, i, j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider doing an outer/inner loop to correctly index row and column:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50);
            rect.setFill(Color.web(colors.get(rand.nextInt(4))));
            rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            grid.add(rect, i, j);
       }
    }
```

To better understand why this works, try printing the `row` and `col` values at the top of the for loop vs printing the `i` and `j` values in this code. You can then see difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the first 4 iterations of the loop you increment both `row` and `column` and in all the other iterations you do not increment them at all but put the rects in the bottom right cell. Furthermore your loop does 26 iterations, not 25 = 5*5.

To correct the error you need to need to increment the row only when you've reached the end of a row and reset the column to 0 at the same time:

```
final int columns = 5:
final int rows = 5
int row = 0;
int column = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < (columns * rows); ++i) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50);
    rect.setFill(Color.web(colors.get(rand.nextInt(4))));
    rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    grid.add(rect, col, row);

    ++column; // move to right

    // if we exceed the available horizontal space, start new row
    if (column >= columns) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use the result of the truncating division and the remainder operator to compute the column/row from `i`

```
for (int i = 0; i < (columns * rows); ++i) {
    row = i / columns;
    column = i % columns;
```

Usually a nested loop as demonstrated in the other answers would be preferable though, but I though I'd provide some alternatives and explain where you went wrong.